# Slack API - Getting a list of members in a private channel

Tags: slack-api

Using the slack api method - [conversations.members](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members). I'm able to retrieve a list of members in a public group.

Hoping someone knows of a way to retrieve a list of members from a private group.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct method - the bot just needed to be added to the group.

Comment: How to add the bot in private channel?